# Save changed background

Tags: jquery, cookies, background, addclass

I made a little piece of code to change the body class on click of a button but the problem is that those changes don't save when refreshing the page.

How do I save those settings when the class is changed?

This is my code:

```
var classes = ['mystics','steampunk', 'love', 'ny', 'olympic', 'pirates'];
var count = 0;
$(function() {  
    $('#bgChange').click(function(e){
        count ++;
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').addClass(classes[teller]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On refreshing the page DOM gets reloaded, hence any earlier changes gets lost, you can use HTML5 Local-storage or Session-storage to remember the changes even if you refresh your page.